# New character $pq$ and $qp$

Tags: alphabet, phonetic

I do not see so far a letter that represents the letters "p" and "q" together. For example, the letters "a" and "e", and "o" and "e" are given respectively by the characters æ and œ. Does such a character exist?

Best regards.

Comment: There is a proposal at https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangscirclejerk/comments/umx9ae/new_ligature_for_pq/. You can also make this in LaTeX, for example `p\kern-4.7pt q` (in text mode, 10pt font). Not very pretty recognizable as a combination of p and q though.

Comment: With lualatex or xelatex you should be able to use the unicode `ȹ` (U+0239) for `qp` directly with a font that has it. I'm not aware of a package that provides it as a single character for pdflatex. I don't think there's a pq digraph or ligature in unicode, but I'm no expert. In what context is that used?

Comment: You can use `\textqplig` with the `tipx` package.

Comment: Great, guys! Brazilian greetings. :)

Comment: Someone should notify Overleaf team about this feature opportunity: it breaks when I add to some math environment.

Comment: @Marijn \kern-2.pt looks better than 4.7 for me. :)

Comment: It's not really an Overleaf issue unless it works ok on an appropriate TeXLive installation, but not on Overleaf.  But we'd need a minimal example to start from to figure that out.

Comment: It complains about the spacing \! I use it in an equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\textqplig` with the `tipx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipx}
\def\!{\negthinspace} % tipx seems to redefine \!

\begin{document}

The qp ligature, \textqplig, is a typographic ligature of Latin q and p.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you try to embed it in a math environment e.g. $\mbox{\textqplig}$ or $\text{\textqplig}$. It breaks for me on Overleaf compiler.

Comment: This package $\texttt{tipx}$ conflicts with others. :(

Comment: The minimal example above with `$\mbox{\textqplig}$` works fine for me on Overleaf.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto: Can you figure out which package is causing the conflict? Maybe there's another workaround.

Comment: Hold my beer!...

Comment: It complains about the spacing \! I use it in an equation.

Comment: I was not aware of this, but `tipx` seems to break `\!` in math mode (but not in text mode). You can add `\def\!{\negthinspace}` after you load the package to make it work again. I can't promise that won't lead to other unforeseen consequences since I'm not sure exactly what the package is doing to `\!`.

Comment: It also complains about command \par. Indeed, the redefinition of command \! clears things out a bit.